# Spring MVC - AlwaysUseFullPath configuration for annotation based mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring MVC application.

I am moving away from XML configuration of the Controllers to annotation based config using `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` to define the URL mapping to controllers.

Previously I defined the mappings in config as follows:

```
   <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">        
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/status/**">statusController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

You will see that I have defined the property `alwaysUseFullPath` as true for my url mappings. I want to set this property for the annotation mappings (`@RequestMapping`) and I have two questions:

1) Is it possible to do this on a class by class basis? e.g. if i want some of my controllers to have this property but some other controllers not to, is that possible?

2) I have seen that it can be set by configuring in XML the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and setting hte property in there (looks like this will apply the property to all annotations) - but I have found [this issue](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81238-Conflict-between-lt-mvc-annotation-driven-gt-and-DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping) - is this resolved now? or is the only way to get around this to not use the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but do you mean something like this :

```
 @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    public AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter(){
    final AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
    annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
    return annotationMethodHandlerAdapter;
    }
```